# Does $f(X) = X$ imply $f$ is identity?

Tags: probability, random-variable

For a random variable $X$, does $f(X) = X$ imply that $f(.)$ is the identity function, at least over the support of $X$?

Comment: Isn't that the definition of "identity function"?

Comment: For a Bernoulli RV, I can think of f that maps 0->0 and 1->1, but is arbitrary everywhere else. So f is not an identity function at all values but only over the support of X. I'm wondering if there's any other case where f(x) is not an identity function but f(X) = X. Does seem unlikely.

Comment: Of course, as you have it in your question, we are talking about the support of X.

Comment: If it only needs to be identity in the support of X, you can find arbitrary cases where it's not the identity function. For example, let X be non-negative, and f(x) = |x|.

Comment: @fm361 No, it isn't. The equality $f\circ X=X$ where $X$ is a function only determines $f$ if $X$ is surjective.

Comment: @Accidental Statistician and drhab: Good points, thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "support of $X$." If you mean the *image* of $X$ as a function, the question is trivial.  If you mean the smallest closed set $A$ for which $\Pr(X\in A)=1,$ then are you allowing exceptions to the equality $f(X)=X$ on a set of measure zero?  If so, that also has a trivial answer.  This leads me to wonder what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @whuber I was solving a problem which stated $E[Y|X] = X$, and was wondering if I could equate that to $\int yp(y|x)dy = x$. It probably is trivial in hindsight.